# How to navigate through button programmatically

Tags: swift4.1

I have created a table view cell in story board and i created a cocoa touch class for it.In that it will have one button, so here i want to navigate to another view controller on clicking on the button programmatically.

This my code

@IBOutlet weak var findOutButton: UIButton!

```
override func awakeFromNib()
{
    super.awakeFromNib()

   findOutButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("action:")), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

}
func action(sender: UIButton) {


let vc5 = self.storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DescriptionViewController") as? DescriptionViewController

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc5!, animated: true)
}
```

Here its showing error in this line

let vc5 = self.storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DescriptionViewController") as? DescriptionViewController
`
like "value of type 'TableViewCell' has no member 'storyboard'.

Thanks in advance.Help me to clear out the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access self.storyboard from your UITableCell. You should navigate from the main ViewController, that contains your UITableView. And for this you need to use delegates. At top of your UITableCell class add this :-

```
protocol CustomTableDelegate {
    func DelegateButtonPressed()
}
class YourClass : UITableViewCell{
var delegate : CustomTableDelegate? = nil

override func awakeFromNib()
{
    super.awakeFromNib()

   findOutButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("action:")), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

}
func action(sender: UIButton) {

self.delegate?.DelegateButtonPressed()
}
}
```

And In your main View Controller in which you have your UITableView, in

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YourClass", for: indexPath) as! YourClass
cell.delegate = self
return cell
}
```

And also add delegate as :-

```
class YOURVIEWCONTROLLER:UIViewController, CustomTableDelegate{
func DelegateButtonPressed(){
let vc5 = self.storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DescriptionViewController") as? DescriptionViewController

    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc5!, animated: true)
}
}
```

Let me know if you find any difficulty using this.

Comment: it worked well thank u so much , i have given the button action in table view cell class thats the prob now its working fine. Thanks again.

Comment: Yup sure I will!

Comment: You haven't done yet. Just click on the upward arrow. and tick button.

Answer (score 0):

Create Completion Block For getting Button Action on View Controller Class

```
class YourCellClass : UITableViewCell{
var completionBlock : ((_ sender : UIButon)->())?

override func awakeFromNib()
{
    super.awakeFromNib()

   findOutButton.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("action:")), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

}
 func action(sender: UIButton) {
   completionBlock?(sender)
 }
}
```

In View Controller Execute the Block

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YourCellClass", for: indexPath) as! YourCellClass

     cell.completionBlock = { (sender) -> Void in

        /* Here sender is button refrence so you can modify property of the button also */

      let vc5 = self.storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DescriptionViewController") as? DescriptionViewController  
      self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc5!, animated: true)
    }

  return cell
}
```